# How to sort a multidimensional string array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, sorting, nested

guys. I'm pretty new to javascript and i'm trying to sort a huge nested array.

Here is a part of the array:

```
      {
      UF: 'AC',
      Cidades: [
        { ID: '79', Nome: 'Acrelândia', Estado: '1' },
        { ID: '80', Nome: 'Assis Brasil', Estado: '1' },
        { ID: '81', Nome: 'Brasiléia', Estado: '1' },
        { ID: '82', Nome: 'Bujari', Estado: '1' },
        { ID: '83', Nome: 'Capixaba', Estado: '1' }
        ]}
      {
      UF: 'AL',
      Cidades: [
        { ID: '101', Nome: 'Água Branca', Estado: '2' },
        { ID: '102', Nome: 'Anadia', Estado: '2' },
        { ID: '103', Nome: 'Arapiraca', Estado: '2' },
        { ID: '104', Nome: 'Atalaia', Estado: '2' },
        { ID: '105', Nome: 'Barra de Santo Antônio', Estado: '2' },
        { ID: '106', Nome: 'Barra de São Miguel', Estado: '2' },
        { ID: '107', Nome: 'Batalha', Estado: '2' }
        ]}
      }
```

These array is a bunch of objects (one per state) with a nested array of all its cities inside of each state object. What i'm trying to do is sort the nested array "Cidades" according to length of each "Nome".

I tried a lot of things with no success. The last thing i tried was this:

```
  arr.forEach((state) => {
    arr.sort((a, b) => {
      return b.Cidades[1] - a.Cidades[1];
    });
  });
```

I also tried writing my own comparison function but also no success

```
  function compare(a, b) {
    if (a.Cidades.Nome < b.Cidades.Nome) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (a.Cidades.Nome > b.Cidades.Nome) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  }
```

Can you guys tell me how can i do this sort and why i'm doing wrong?

tks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sort()` and `forEach()`

```js
var data = [
  {
    UF: 'AC',
    Cidades: [
      { ID: '79', Nome: 'Acrelândia', Estado: '1' },
      { ID: '80', Nome: 'Assis Brasil', Estado: '1' },
      { ID: '81', Nome: 'Brasiléia', Estado: '1' },
      { ID: '82', Nome: 'Bujari', Estado: '1' },
      { ID: '83', Nome: 'Capixaba', Estado: '1' }
    ]
  },
  {
    UF: 'AL',
    Cidades: [
      { ID: '101', Nome: 'Água Branca', Estado: '2' },
      { ID: '102', Nome: 'Anadia', Estado: '2' },
      { ID: '103', Nome: 'Arapiraca', Estado: '2' },
      { ID: '104', Nome: 'Atalaia', Estado: '2' },
      { ID: '105', Nome: 'Barra de Santo Antônio', Estado: '2' },
      { ID: '106', Nome: 'Barra de São Miguel', Estado: '2' },
      { ID: '107', Nome: 'Batalha', Estado: '2' }
    ]
  }
]
 
data.forEach(state => {
  state.Cidades.sort((a, b) => a.Nome.length - b.Nome.length)
})
 
console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort it by taking `length` of `Nome` property

```js
var data=[{ UF: 'AC', Cidades: [ { ID: '79', Nome: 'Acrelândia', Estado: '1' }, { ID: '80', Nome: 'Assis Brasil', Estado: '1' }, { ID: '81', Nome: 'Brasiléia', Estado: '1' }, { ID: '82', Nome: 'Bujari', Estado: '1' }, { ID: '83', Nome: 'Capixaba', Estado: '1' } ]}, { UF: 'AL', Cidades: [ { ID: '101', Nome: 'Água Branca', Estado: '2' }, { ID: '102', Nome: 'Anadia', Estado: '2' }, { ID: '103', Nome: 'Arapiraca', Estado: '2' }, { ID: '104', Nome: 'Atalaia', Estado: '2' }, { ID: '105', Nome: 'Barra de Santo Antônio', Estado: '2' }, { ID: '106', Nome: 'Barra de São Miguel', Estado: '2' }, { ID: '107', Nome: 'Batalha', Estado: '2' } ]} ];

var result = data.map(arr=>{
   arr.Cidades = arr.Cidades.sort((a,b)=>a.Nome.length-b.Nome.length);
   return arr;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to sort each "Cidades" array by the length of its field "Nome".
You are try following solution.

```
Array.forEach( ( data ) => {
    data.cidades.sort( (a,b) =>{
        return b.Nome.length - a.Nome.length; // replace for reverse order sorting
    });
});
```

You can use "return a.Nome.length - b.Nome.length" to sort it in reverse order.

Hope it will help! :)